# How to build a long interface using interface builder

Tags: iphone, ios, interface, interface-builder

I build an UIViewController, that higher than iPhone screen ( the height is 900px ), i build it using UIScrollView.

In the Interface Builder, how to put an View in the bottom part of the UIScrollview ? i've tried using freeform in the inspector -> Simulated Metrics, but every time i move back to the ipad/iphone screensize, the views are mess. And when i ran it in the simulator, the view still a mess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add a view programmatically and make it subview for the scrollview, i don't know how to do it using IB.

If you want to try programmatically can try something like:

```
UIView*myView=[[UIView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 200)];   
[myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; // Just for testing purpose
[scrollView addSubview:myView];
```

Comment: Don't forget to set your scrollView's `contentSize` property as well!

Comment: It's just something that trips me up every time - it would be nice if a UIScrollView could detect changes and automatically do it for us but I guess there's probably a reason why it doesn't.

Comment: Same here :S, as there seem to be no option to set up content size in IB too (atleast i haven't been able to find it)

Comment: ah ok thanks! anyways i've been one of the guys who switched from coding the interface to using the builder so i wasn't very sure.

Comment: great, thanks guys. Yes, too bad you can't set the content size of the Scrollview in the IB.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do a bit of it programatically I'm afraid but you can do most of it in a xib.

Your xib would contain a UIView that's your normal view, containing your scrollview.

It would also contain *another* UIView; this will be as long as you want and will be your scrollview's contents.

In your .h file, have a property like this and attach it to the second UIView in your xib

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *scrollingContents;
```

and in your viewDidLoad, that's where you attach the contents inside the scroll view

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:scrollingContents];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = scrollingContents.bounds.size;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dean, it seems i have to do it programmatically

Comment: Either would work, it's up to you! Though it's worth knowing that unpacking a xib is faster than doing it in code so if your contents are complicated or are going to be displayed a lot you might have to revisit the xib option. Though at the end of the day, do whatever works best for you!

Comment: Yes, too bad that the Interface builder not support if the views exceed the iPhone limit, you can't drag and drop to the most bottom of scrollview

Comment: You _can_ do that; in interface builder just choose size->freeform (or don't choose a status-bar type) in the 'simulated metrics' section on the right hand side. You can then set it to be any size you want.

Comment: That was the question actually. When i tried the freeform, and build it, the views are in the wrong position. I don't know how to fix it

Comment: How can I set it to any size I want after I check it freeform?